# Check for null or empty value in placeholder text

Tags: javascript, jquery, dust.js

I have a dust.js template that renders inputs based on a hash I am getting from the server. My hangup is that if the hash is empty I still get an input box rendered with an empty placeholder value, how can I check if the placeholder value is null and then hide that box?

```
<div class='criteria-input'>
  <input type='text' placeholder='{attribute}' value='{value}' size='20'/>
  <span class="close">X</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the "Special Sections" documentation of dust.js here: http://akdubya.github.io/dustjs/#guide

The "exists" syntax is what you want, so that you can do this:

```
{?attribute}
<div class='criteria-input'>
  <input type='text' placeholder='{attribute}' value='{value}' size='20'/>
  <span class="close">X</span>
</div>
{/attribute}
```

Answer (score 2):

here you go:

```
$('input').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('placeholder')=='' || $(this).attr('placeholder')==null){
        $(this).parent().hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the code that checks if the placeholder is empy

```
var placeholder = $('input').attr('placeholder');
if(placeholder == ''){

} else{

}
```

Comment: what if we have more than one input?